# Multiply different value in javascript by getting select tags of html (currency converter)

Tags: javascript, html, select

I want to make a currency convert. mean using select tag of  html select different currency and multiply with input value using javascript

```js
function getInputValue(){
    // Selecting the input element and get its value 
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value=currency;
    var dollar = inputVal*1.12;
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
    answer.value= dollar;
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value=currency;
    var pound = inputVal*0,86;
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
    answer.value= pound;
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value=currency;
    var pak = inputVal*170;
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
    answer.value= pak;        
}
        
function newVal(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```html
  <select id="currency">
    <option value="volvo" >Doller</option>
    <option value="volvo">Pound</option>
    <option value="volvo">Pak</option>
  
</select>
```

Comment: Why do all your options have the same value?

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach would be to use each option's `value` to hold the currency's exchange rate, like so:

```
<select id="currency">
    <option value="1.12" >Dollar</option>
    <option value="0.86">Pound</option>
    <option value="170">Pak</option>
</select>
```

Then, in your Javascript function, you can simply multiply the amount by the selected option's `value` attribute:

```
function getInputValue(){
    //assuming you are typing the amount in an input with id "myInput"
    var amount = document.getElementById("myInput").value; 
    var rate = document.getElementById("currency").value;
    var result = amount * rate;

    //output the result to HTML
    //(assuming you have a div or element with id "result")
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

---

On a side note, in your original code, I am not sure what you were trying to do with:

```
var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value=currency;
```

Did you mean to real the value of `currency`? Then you should have done:

```
var inputVal = document.getElementById("currency").value;
```

Comment: Thank you for time and reply.

Comment: @UmarAbdulSattar You're welcome! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking this post as answer. Have a good day!

Comment: Thank you for time and reply. kindly guide me how  i show result using html output?